# Автозавершение скобки в Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Всем привет!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как настроить автозавершение скобки в MVS2012. То есть, чтобы при открытии скобки сразу же появлялась закрывающая блок скобка?

Answer (score 1):

- Стандартный способ: Tools => Options => Text Editor => All languages (либо выбираете интересующий вас язык) => General => Automatic brace comletion
- C помощью Resharper'a: Resharper => Options => Environment => Editor => Edotor behavior => Auto-insert closing brace